# What is the number of 7 card poker hands which contain 3 of a kind and the other 4 are not the same?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, combinations, poker

Im solving this problem in two ways but i don't know which is correct, because they give different results.

### First Way

- I calculate the number of hands for the 4 possible forms of accepting hands:

1. (aaa -  bbb - c) : $\binom{13}{2} \binom{4}{3}^2~\binom{11}{1} \binom{4}{1} $
2. (aaa - bb - cc) : $\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{3}~\binom{12}{2} \binom{4}{2}^2
   $
3. (aaa - bb - c - d): $\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{3} ~\binom{12}{1} \binom{4}{2} ~\binom{11}{2} \binom{4}{1}^2$
4. (aaa - b - c - d - e): $\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{3} ~\binom{12}{4} \binom{4}{1}^4$

- Add all of them and I get:
  $\left| A \right| = 10062624$

### Second Way

- I calculate all the unordered seven card hands of the form {aaa - ****}:

  $\left| A_1 \right| = \binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{3} \binom{48}{4}$

  Choose 1 from the 13 ranks, choose 3 from 4 of the cards in that rank and
  then choose 4 of the 48 remaining cards.
- I calculate all the unordered seven card hands of the form {aaa - bbbb}:

  $\left| A_2 \right| = \binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{3} \binom{12}{1} \binom{4}{4}$

  Choose 1 from the 13 ranks, choose 3 from 4 of the cards in that rank, choose 1
  from the 12 remaining ranks and then choose 4 of the 4 cards in that rank.
- And then I subtract $\left| A_2 \right|$ from $\left| A_1 \right|$ and I get:
  $\left| A_2 \right| - \left| A_1 \right| = 10117536$

It seems that when using the second method, I might be counting the (aaa - bbb - c) sequence in 7-card hands twice, because when I subtract it from the total count, I end up with the same result as the first method. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the other four are not the same?  Do you mean that they have different ranks?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig No. I meant that the other four aren't all the same rank. For example we could have a pair or even another three of a kind in those 4 cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed : $10117536 - \underbrace{\binom{13}2\binom 4 3^2\binom {11}1\binom 41}_{\large 54912} =10062624$

So indeed your second method was overcounted the pattern aaa-bbb-c .

Why?  After selecting a triple of one rank, $\big(\binom{12*4}{4}-\binom{12}1\binom 44\big)$ *tries to* count selection of 4 cards from the remaining ranks that are not all the same rank, **but** this includes the possibility of selecting a second triple.  Thus overcounting like so:

- Select 3 aces, then 4 cards( including 3 duces and singletons, etc ), or
- Select 3 duces, then 4 cards( including 3 aces and singletons, etc ), or
- $\quad\vdots$

**$\therefore$ You do need to discount having that second triple.**

Comment: Thank you very much